# Write the digits of a number into an array

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want to calculate with seperated digits of a very long number. How can I do this in Python2.7? I thought about somehow write the digits in an array so that I can access the digits with array(x):

```
number = 123456789123456789
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The problem is, that the number has so many digits, that it would take very long to do that manually. So how can I do this automatically?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) and [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) functions like this

```
print map(int, str(number))
```

`str` function converts the `number` to a string.

`map` function applies the `int` function to each and every element of stringifed number, to convert the string to an integer.

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you are doing this again and again, like in a loop, then list comprehension will be faster than the `map` approach

```
number = 123456789123456789
from timeit import timeit
print timeit("map(int, str(number))", "from __main__ import number")
print timeit("[int(dig) for dig in str(number)]", "from __main__ import number")
```

**Output on my machine**

```
12.8388962786
10.7739010307
```

Comment: +1 I really like the intelligent use of map here which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a list comprehension link this.

```
array = [int(x) for x in str(number)]
```

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative, the purely mathematical solution is below. By repeatedly dividing by 10 and taking the remainder you can extract each digit.

```
n = 123456789123456789
result = []
while n != 0:
    n, d = divmod(n, 10)
    result.append(int(d))
result.reverse()
print result # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Good job. Two minor improvements: divmod returns ints when applied to an int, so `int(d)` is not needed and `insert(0,d)` instead of `append` to get rid of the reverse step.

Comment: The questioner gave `123456789123456789` as the sample data, so (at least on 2.7) `divmod` returns a long. `insert(0,d)` would run in quadratic time - I'd much rather have a `reverse` and get linear time. Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: +1 You can also use [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) here for faster insertion on left side.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate over each digit in number and push into an array. Try this

```
result = []
for d in str(number):
    result.append (int(d))

print result
```

Comment: The answer from thefourtheye appears better, but this works too

Comment: @NaveedHasan yeah, I really liked the answer from thefourtheye. It took me about 2 minutes to write this code and test it out. Meanwhile, thefourtheye posted an awesome answer :|